# Initialising an NSMutableArray and add an int objet causing app crash (error inside) - Obj-C / Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

So I am building a simple, two-view application in which a user generates a score, and then navigates to the `LeaderboardViewController` where their latest score is added to an array, and shown in a table view.

I have everything pretty much working 
1. Passing score from initial view controller to the `LeaderboardViewController`
2. Log the `_scoreToBeAdded` int variable to the console to make sure I have it in the new view controller
2. Created a dummy array and populate a table view with the array data.

**Problems**

The only problem is, I can't seem to add a new object (`_scoreToBeAdded`) to the `scores` NSMutableArray without causing a crash.

In addition, I'm also unsure the best way to initialise the array without needing to add the "TODO, dummy data" objects in the array.

Any guidance is much appreciated! :)

Crash message:

```
2015-04-06 12:22:20.627 Bugland[15976:607] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509
2015-04-06 12:22:20.635 Bugland[15976:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Edit: If I edit out the following line,

```
[scores addObject:anumber];
```

I get no problem, and no app crash.

LeaderboardViewController.m

```
#import "LeaderboardViewController.h"

@interface LeaderboardViewController ()

@end

@implementation LeaderboardViewController

{
    NSMutableArray *scores; //Init array
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize some dummy array and table data 

    scores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"TODO: Enter real data here", @"TODO: Enter real data here", nil];

    //Turn the _scoreToBeAdded into an NSNumber
    NSNumber *anumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_scoreToBeAdded];

    //Attempt to add the number to the array - this line is a problem
    [scores addObject:anumber]; //This line is causing issues.

    NSLog(@"Leaderboard loaded w new score to add %i", _scoreToBeAdded);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [scores count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [scores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //I assume this line is also causing an issue based on the error log. 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to create cell yourself? It's redundant. deuqueueResuableCellWithIdentifier always returns a cell.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on return cell, and see what type of object is it returning.

Comment: Do you define cellIdentifier i.e simpleTableIdentifier from storyboard , xib? The problem is not the line you mentioned but  `cell` is either nil or not type of 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: Nope not from storyboard, all inside the last function in that code above.

Comment: Have you tried to debug cellForRowAtIndexPath method ?
First Check if cell is actually created? then
Cast the [scores objectAtIndex:index] to NSString and assign it to textLabel

Comment: Checked your Edit : Are you adding NSString values like
scores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"TODO: Enter real data here", @"TODO: Enter real data here", nil];
and then adding NSNumber and using both like Strings (without casting) ?? 
Either you convert score while adding it in array or convert it to nsstring while assinging it to textLabel.

Comment: Ah, yep, I've most likely got to convert it to an NSString. Thanks Samir, will try that.

Comment: Worked, thanks Samir!